# UIAlertView with UIImageView in accessoryView

Tags: uiimageview, ios8, uialertview, accessoryview

I am giving an UIImageView in the UIAlertView's *accessoryView* by the following code:

```
   UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]init];

   [alertView addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
   [alertView addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    UIImageView *someImageView = /*initialization code */;

   [someImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,40 ,20)];

   [alertView someImageView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
   [alertView show];
```

The above code works fine with iOS7 but since the update to iOS8 the alertView looks elongated and disoriented. I have tried changing the constraints and the aspect ratio of the image that is set in the UIImageView.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a supported use of `UIAlertView`:

> The `UIAlertView` class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

Additionally, `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 8.

You should build your own view to present, or use one of the many open-sourced options on GitHub/CocoaControls, like [SDCAlertView](https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView) or [ios-custom-alertview](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview).

Comment: Won't this be against any App review guidelines?